# Manipulate ajax response

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, ajax, object

I have a ajax post method. I get an object from the backend

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: URL_one,
        data: submitData
}).then(function (response) {
       console.log("Ajax response", response);
   });
```

and when i do a console.log(response); inside the post method, i see the following data.

```
>Object{Info:Array[200]}
      >Info:Array[200]
                >[0-99]  
                      >0:Object
                          name:'Ashley'
                          on_pay: true
                          valid:"0"
                >[100-199]
```

So each array has objects like one mentioned above with name, on_pay and valid. I want to do the following
Since all on_pay values are true in my case, i need to convert it to false. Also valid has string of 0. I need to put all values as blank instead of 0.

Is it possible to do ?? Can someone please shed some light on these.

Comment: Post your JSON response.

Comment: Is the response a format such as JSON or XML? You could convert it on the client side but it would be better if you could modify the server code to send the response you want.

Comment: @Dudevan- isnt the console.log(response) the same ?

Comment: @Ayesha - No. It is not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, `response` is an array of items.  You want to keep those items intact, but turn the `on_pay` property `false` and `valid` to an empty string.

You can use [Array::map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to transform each item.

```
/*jslint node:true*/

"use strict";

// I am assuming your response looks something like this
var response = {
    Info: [
        {
            name: "Ashley",
            on_pay: true,
            valid: "0"
        },
        {
            name: "Jim",
            on_pay: true,
            valid: "0"
        },
        {
            name: "John",
            on_pay: true,
            valid: "0"
        }
    ]
};

// This will produce a new variable that will hold the transformed Info array
var fixedResponseInfo = response.Info.map(function (item) {
    item.on_pay = false;
    item.valid = "";
    return item;
});

// This will edit the response.Info array in place
response.Info.forEach(function (item) {
    item.on_pay = false;
    item.valid = "";
});

console.log(fixedResponseInfo);
console.log(response);
```

This will keep your original response variable and produce a new variable `fixedResponseInfo` that contains the transformed array.  If you don't care whether data in `response` is changed, you can use [`Array::forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) to iterate instead.

Comment: @Ayesha I noted the difference between `map` and `forEach`.  If you don't care about whether the data in response changes, you can use `forEach` as leo.fcx said in his answer.

Comment: Strangely, both response and fixedResponse give same result. i.e. new values overwitten to item.on_pay and item.values in both the outputs.

Answer (score 2):

Considering the JSON structure that you show, following should work to change the `on_pay` value:

```
response.Info.forEach(function(item){
    item.on_pay = false;
});
```

Comment: @leo.fcx- i wish i cld select ur answer as well. thanks for prompt help